# Get name of subclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Lets say I have I class called

```
a = Person::User::Base
```

How can I get only the last subclass called `Base`.

The way i know how to do this is:

```
a.to_s.split('::').last

=> "Base"
```

**Is there a better way?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you use Rails (ActiveSupport):

`a.to_s.demodulize`

If you use POR (plain-ol-Ruby), yes, it's your way:

`a.to_s.split('::').last`

Comment: When I used this command in Rails I got as Result `"Base:0x007fd84b37b948>"`

Comment: Sorry this happened because I already had initialized an Object! Thanks again